# Find a fundamental set of solutions for $t^{2}y^{(4)}+ty^{(3)}+y^{(2)}-4y=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find a fundamental set of solutions for $t^{2}y^{(4)}+ty^{(3)}+y^{(2)}-4y=0$.

I haven't learned any techniques on how to solve an $n$th order DE with nonconstant coefficients besides the Euler-Cauchy equation. Any ideas will be helpful!

Comment: Wolfram Alpha doesn’t find nice solutions to your ODE ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%5E2+y’’’’%28t%29%2Bt+y’’’%28t%29%2Bt%5E2+y’’%28t%29-4y%28t%29%3D%3D0).) The best you may be able to do is find power-series solutions to your ODE.

Comment: What about Laplace transform?  You get a new DE of order 2, but coefficients are polynomials of degree 4.  Maple does solve that DE (in terms of Bessel functions $I, K$ with imaginary index), but cannot do the inverse Laplace transform to get the solution of the original equation.  Why does this produce only 2 solutions?  Perhaps because the other solutions have divergent laplace transform?

Comment: @GEdgar You should double the amount of solutions because the Laplace transform gives two more parameters to work with for each solution to that DE: $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be tackled with the Frobenius method, which seeks to find a power series solution for the differential equation. Let $\displaystyle y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^{n+r}$ and see that we then have

$$r(r-1)[(r-2)^2+1]a_0t^{r-2}+(r+1)r[(r-1)^2+1]a_1t^{r-1}+\\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty[(n+r+2)(n+r+1)[(n+r)^2+1]a_{n+2}-4a_n]t^{n+r}=0$$

Equating coefficients gives $r=0$ and

$$a_{n+2}=\frac4{(n+2)(n+1)(n^2+1)}a_n$$

This gives us two solutions:

$$y_1={}_0F_3\left(;\frac12,-\frac i2,\frac i2;\frac14t^2\right)=1+2t^2+\frac2{15}t^4+\mathcal O(t^6)$$

$$y_2=t\cdot{}_0F_3\left(;1,\frac{1-i}2,\frac{1+i}2;\frac14t^2\right)=t+\frac13t^3+\frac1{150}t^5+\mathcal O(t^7)$$

When $a_1=0$ we also get two more solutions from $r=2\pm i$ and

$$a_{n+2}=\frac4{(n+4\pm i)(n+3\pm i)[(n+2\pm i)^2+1]}a_n$$

which resolve to

$$y_3=t^{2-i}\cdot{}_0F_3\left(;\frac{4-i}2,\frac{3-i}2,1-i;\frac14t^2\right)=t^{2-i}+\frac{2+9i}{170}t^{4-i}+\mathcal O(t^{6-i})$$

$$y_4=t^{2+i}\cdot{}_0F_3\left(;\frac{4+i}2,\frac{3+i}2,1+i;\frac14t^2\right)=t^{2+i}+\frac{2-9i}{170}t^{4+i}+\mathcal O(t^{6+i})$$

Since these are conjugates of each other, we can add subtract them from each other to form their real counterparts:

$$y_+=\frac{y_3+y_4}2$$

$$y_-=\frac{y_3-y_4}{2i}$$

Notes:

- The case of $a_1=0$ and $r=1$ is just a special case of the original with $r=0$. The same is true for $a_0=0$ and $r=-1,1\pm i$. This is simply because they are integer shifts of $r$.
- ${}_pF_q$ is the [generalized hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html).

Answer (score 2):

Maple also fails to find closed form soltuion.  In series form, Maple provides these four solutions:
$$
y_1=\,{t}^{2+i} \left( (1+ \left( {\frac{1}{
85}}-{\frac {9\,i}{170}} \right) {t}^{2}+ \left( -{\frac{73}{327080}}-
{\frac {21\,i}{65416}} \right) {t}^{4}+ \left( -{\frac{11}{16354000}}-
{\frac {i}{3774000}} \right) {t}^{6}+ \left( -{\frac{2211}{
4605090152000}}+{\frac {133\,i}{3453817614000}} \right) {t}^{8}+O
 \left( {t}^{10} \right) ) \right)
\\
y_2=\,{t}^{2-i} \left( (1+
 \left( {\frac{1}{85}}+{\frac {9\,i}{170}} \right) {t}^{2}+ \left( -{
\frac{73}{327080}}+{\frac {21\,i}{65416}} \right) {t}^{4}+ \left( -{
\frac{11}{16354000}}+{\frac {i}{3774000}} \right) {t}^{6}+ \left( -{
\frac{2211}{4605090152000}}-{\frac {133\,i}{3453817614000}} \right) {t
}^{8}+O \left( {t}^{10} \right) ) \right)
\\
y_3=\,t \left( (1+{
\frac{1}{3}}{t}^{2}+{\frac{1}{150}}{t}^{4}+{\frac{1}{40950}}{t}^{6}+{
\frac{1}{36855000}}{t}^{8}+O \left( {t}^{10} \right) ) \right)
\\
y_4=\, \left( (2+4\,{t}^{2}+{\frac{4}{15}}{t}^{4}+{\frac{8}{3825}}{t}
^{6}+{\frac{4}{990675}}{t}^{8}+O \left( {t}^{10} \right) ) \right)  
$$